# How can I extract those bits from 16bit LE data?

Tags: python, image, numpy, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've got **16 bit data** in the following LE bit format:

B4 | B5 | C1 | C2 | C3 | D1 | D2 | D3

A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | B1 | B2 | B3

Each letter represents one data category that I want to extract and make a seperate image from.

Using this python code, I managed to create an image from the A layer, but I did not succeed in extracting B, C and D.

```
# using numpy and PIL
data = np.fromfile(i, dtype=np.dtype('<u2')).reshape(size, size)
A = ((data & 31) - 1).astype('uint8')
image_A = Image.fromarray(A)
```

Does anyone know how that would work?

[Sample data (512x512)](https://easyupload.io/xl3l5a), [Output A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFh3j.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary of bitmasks and some bit twiddling to compute the requisite shifts:

```python
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def extract_mask(arr, mask):
    # bit twiddling magic (count trailing zeros)
    shift = int(np.log2(mask & -mask))
    return (arr & mask) >> shift

masks = {
    "A": 0b000_000_00000_11111,
    "B": 0b000_000_11111_00000,
    "C": 0b000_111_00000_00000,
    "D": 0b111_000_00000_00000,
}

filename = "512x512.buffer"
size = 512
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype="<u2").reshape(size, size)
images = {
    k: Image.fromarray(extract_mask(data, mask).astype(np.uint8))
    for k, mask in masks.items()
}
```

Comment: Working great, thank you! The only difference to my A result is that your values are 1 higher (255 => 0, 0 => 1), but that's not a problem, actually quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an easy way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image as 16-bit LE and reshape
size = 512
data = np.fromfile('512x512.buffer', dtype='<u2').reshape(size, size)

A = Image.fromarray(((data      ) & 31).astype(np.uint8))
B = Image.fromarray(((data >>  5) & 31).astype(np.uint8))
C = Image.fromarray(((data >> 10) &  7).astype(np.uint8))
D = Image.fromarray(((data >> 13) &  7).astype(np.uint8))
```